# Speed of sound in gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, acoustics

The pressure of a gas is increased but the temperature remains constant. Will the speed of sound in the medium change or remain unchanged ?

I think since speed of sound in a medium, $v = \sqrt{\dfrac{P}{\rho}}$, the increase in pressure will increase the density as well and for this reason, the speed will remain the same.

Am I correct ?

Or, will I need to consider thermodynamic effects or something that I'm missing in my analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

A dilute gas (approximately) satisfies the ideal gas law, $P=nT$. This means that the speed of sound is (approximately) independent of pressure, and only a function of temperature,
$$
c_s=\sqrt{\frac{5T}{3m}}
$$
Here, I have corrected a few mistakes in the question. The speed of sound is not $c_s^2=P/\rho$, but 
$$
 c_s^2 = \left.\frac{\partial P}{\partial\rho}\right|_{S/N}
$$
where the derivative is taken at constant entropy per particle (this is the origin of the factor 5/3). In a real gas, the speed of sound has some dependence on pressure, but the sign and magnitude of the effect depends on the interaction between the molecules in the gas.